# How can you approximate number of bound states in a harmonic oscillator potential $V$ and also for a Dirac delta function using uncertainty principle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, dirac-delta-distributions

How can you approximate the number of bound states in a harmonic oscillator potential $V$ and also for a Dirac delta function using the uncertainty principle?

Comment: Welcome to PSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/637433/2451